# Installing Flow with a new React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I am trying to get started with Flow with React Native app but I always get an error that the node_module is not properly configured with Flow.

Ultimate in the .flowconfig I added a line to ignore everything  under the `node_module` director but that gives me an error that it cannot find    'react native'

```
>     Spawned flow server (pid=70665)
>     Logs will go to /private/tmp/flow/zSUserszSaxxxzSWorkspacezSprojectzSAwesomeProject.log
>     Monitor logs will go to /private/tmp/flow/zSUserszSaxxxzSWorkspacezSprojectzSAwesomeProject.monitor_log
>     Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> App.js:3:40
>     
>     Cannot resolve module react-native.
>     
>          1│ /* @flow */
>          2│ import React from 'react';
>          3│ import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
>          4│
>          5│ export default class App extends React.Component {
>          6│   render() {
> 
> Error
> ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> App.js:5:34
> 
> Cannot use property Component [1] with less than 1 type argument.
> 
>      App.js
>       2│ import React from 'react';
>       3│ import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
>       4│
>       5│ export default class App extends React.Component {
>       6│   render() {
```

what is the proper way to install Flow in a new RN app

> create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
>
> cd AwesomeProject
>   npm start

Answer (score 0):

There is the troubl... 
When you mark `node_modules` as ignored by flow, you prevent flow refinements of libs... I guess it`s ok to reconcile with some errors inside `node_modules` and to hope it will be fixed by libs owners =)

Comment: What does your file look like? How should I set it up?

Comment: just a default - https://monosnap.com/file/9A7hBCFGpOa2cXnrEm02aYU6TGnh9H.png and I have about 15 flow errors inside a node_modules

Answer (score 0):

There's a few steps...

1. Use the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) repo to install Flow library definitions ("libdefs") for your node_modules packages
2. In your `.flowconfig`, ignore some more react-native packages. I use Expo, so you might not need all these:

Something like...

```
[ignore]    
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/editions
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/npm
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/vendor/bundle

      ; Ignore various node_modules for react-native
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/react-native/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/expo/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/react-navigation/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/xdl/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/reqwest/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/metro-bundler/.*
      <PROJECT_ROOT>/frontend/native/node_modules/metro/.*
```

There are some community definitions of react native flow types floating around like [this one](https://gist.github.com/lelandrichardson/c037f46885af67ceb447091c908d1471), but I've found it more buggy than it's worth and just `any` all the components, [like this](https://gist.github.com/AndrewSouthpaw/2321242a7c5bca58ab3f35c4ec7fb9bd). Missing the type definitions hasn't hurt me at all.